# Drupal 6 Views: selection rules and affiliate domains

Tags: drupal, view

I'm having a problem with a View not showing up on an affiliate domain.

There are two new domains which are both to serve up the same content as another existing domain. All content to be served resides in the Drupal database.

We have two main sites w/content, a US version and a European version. The new domains are to serve up the European site.

I added the two new domain records via the domain access module and then went through and added those two new domains to the "Publish to" for all affiliate content that was currently on the European site.

I went through Pages and modified the selection rules to include the new domains.

The particular page has a pane containing a view. That page is at the url 'xxx/press'.

On the Euro site, everything works fine. On the new domains, all content shows and menus work except on the xx/press page, the view doesn't show. The page is coming up and the header node shows so it's just the specific view.

Since that view is on a Page content-type and that Page has selection rules which specify the new domains as a means to show, I'm not sure why it's not showing up.

Is there anywhere else besides the selection-rules of the actual Page that the view is being called on that could limit when/where that View shows?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Too much control!! For the record, in the Views there was one language setting under Filters and the language setting of the new domains didn't match that one.

Amazing that exclusion of content occurs in so many areas and ways! It's like visiting Photoshop all over again and looking at ways to make drop shadows.